# jquery mobile's popup widget doesn't play well with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile, popup

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the issue in jsfiddle, but this test file reproduces the issue: [github file](https://github.com/kanesee/chrome-dialog-back-issue/blob/master/test-dialog-back.html)

Basically, I have a standard popup and a close button inside that popup. I can open the popup. I can close the popup. I can do this over and over again without a problem.

However, when I bind the "popupafterclose" event to the popup, which reopens the popup after receiving that event. Now something weird happens.
On my iPhone 5S's Chrome (v38.0.2125.67), after the second close, the page goes back beyond the popup and to the previous page, as if it was hitting "back" twice.

This only happens on my phone's chrome. The test page works fine on my phone's safari. it also works fine on my mac's chrome (v38.0.2125.104).

I suspect this may be some sort of bug prevention mechanism (like preventing too many popups or infinite loops), but wanted to confirm. I'm hoping I'm just doing something wrong in my code.

If you comment out the "popupafterclose" event, you'll see that you can open/close the popup again and again in every browser including mobile chrome. But automatically re-opening the popup and closing it leads to backing out twice.

You may be wondering why I would want to immediately open the popup after I just closed it. My app has a "play" function that initiates the popup. Upon closing it, I want it to continue to "play" after the popup closes, and some time later, the popup may initiate the popup again. After closing that second instance of the popup, my app backs out of itself.

Comment: Are you adding `data-history="false"` to popup?

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks Omar!
Can you explain why this is needed though, when it works without it on other browsers and platforms?

Comment: Because upon closing a popup, URL changes which fires `popstate` and `haschange` events and then navigates back in history. It should work the same on all browsers, so you may need to open an issue on GitHub. I was able to reproduce on chrome, I'll test it on Safari. Edit: Safari Mobile iOS 8 is fine, Chrome Mobile latest nope!

Comment: Are you saying that mobile chrome is doing the right thing, and all other browsers (mobile safari, desktop chrome) are not?

Comment: Could be, I have to test it thoroughly.

Comment: I think it's more complex than what you're suggesting though because the issue only arises when the popup is opened in the same thread of execution as the "popupafterclose" event. If it's opened by a user-initiated action, it's fine. But your solution argues you understand this more than I do...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63816/discussion-between-kane-and-omar).